# Adjust threshold in cros_val_score sklearn for Lasso

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, lasso-regression

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965700/adjust-threshold-cros-val-score-sklearn) that trained a LGBM model but i would like to know how to adapt it for Lasso. I know the prediction may not necessarily be between 0 and 1, but I would like to try this model. I have tried this but it doesnt work:

```
import numpy as np 
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

X, y = make_classification(n_features=10, random_state=0, n_classes=2, n_samples=1000, n_informative=8)

class Lasso(Lasso):
    def predict(self,X, threshold=0.5):
        result = super(Lasso, self).predict_proba(X)
        predictions = [1 if p>threshold else 0 for p in result[:,0]]
        return predictions

clf = Lasso(alpha=0.05)
clf.fit(X,y)

precision = cross_val_score(Lasso(),X,y,cv=5,scoring='precision')
```

I get

```
UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific model class you chose (`Lasso()`) is actually used for regression problems, as it minimizes penalized square loss, which is not appropriate in your case.  Instead, you can use `LogisticRegression()` with `L1` penalty to optimize a logistic function with a Lasso penalty. To control the regularization strength, the `C=` parameter is used (see [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)).

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

X, y = make_classification(
    n_features=10, random_state=0, n_classes=2, n_samples=1000, n_informative=8
)

class LassoLR(LogisticRegression):
    def predict(self,X, threshold=0.5):
        result = super(LassoLR, self).predict_proba(X)
        predictions = [1 if p>threshold else 0 for p in result[:,0]]
        return predictions

clf = LassoLR(penalty='l1', solver='liblinear', C=1.)
clf.fit(X,y)

precision = cross_val_score(LassoLR(),X,y,cv=5,scoring='precision')
print(precision)
# array([0.04166667, 0.08163265, 0.1010101 , 0.125     , 0.05940594])
```